# Find inverse of $g \circ f$

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I have to find the inverse function of $g \circ f$ in terms of $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$. Ive tried using $ix$ and $iy$, but  haven't managed to solve it.

Could somebody give me a tip on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you work it out yourself in the specific case of $g(x) = 2x$ and $f(x) = x+1$, and then generalise?

Comment: Think about what functions you can pre-compose and post-compose with $f \circ g$ to get the identity maps.

Comment: @PatrickStevens unfortunately i can't do it... I'm pretty new to this. I know how to solve it with the examples you gave, but can't work out the generalised form.

Answer (score 3):

$y=g(f(x))$, inverse $\implies x=g(f(y)) \implies g^{-1}(x)=f(y) \implies f^{-1}(g^{-1}(x))=y$

Comment: How did you go from $y=g(f(x))$ to $x=g(f(y))$ because the textbook doesnt have that. Is it a rule ore something?

Comment: And how can $y$ be the regular function and the inverse one at the same time?

Comment: According to the definition of inverse functions, for some function $f$, $y=f(x)$, and the inverse of that function is $x=f(y)$. Same applies for $y=g(f(x))$. For more information about the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function